# Search the records of visible = 1

Tags: mysql, search

I have a problem 
when I get records from the database

```
mysql_select_db($database_Photo_con, $Photo_con);
$query_rsPhoto = "SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE visible = 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
```

This shows me all records with visible = 1

if search

```
mysql_select_db($database_Photo_con, $Photo_con);
$query_rsPhoto = sprintf("SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE caption LIKE %s OR caption_2 LIKE %s  AND visible = 1 ", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"));
```

it shows me all
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: How many rows return the first and the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the operator precedence (AND has higher priority than OR), so you should use brackets.

```
$query_rsPhoto = sprintf("SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE (caption LIKE %s OR caption_2 LIKE %s)  AND visible = 1 ", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"));
```

And if the GetSQLValueString do not return string with quotes, you have to add them in the query

```
$query_rsPhoto = sprintf("SELECT * FROM photographs WHERE (caption LIKE '%s' OR caption_2 LIKE '%s')  AND visible = 1 ", GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"),GetSQLValueString("%" . $colname_rsPhoto . "%", "text"));
```

Comment: for now it works, thank you very much for your time and answers I have seven records in the database where v = 1 and shows me only 7 when i click http://localhost/dwwithphp/public/admin/list_photos_3.php?query=&button=search